# Optimization of a function with several arguments using neural network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, mathematical-optimization

I have a function `F(args: tuple) => tuple` with 11 arguments that yields 4-elements-tuple as a result.
The project uses a `tensorflow` library.

**How should I implement this with the help of a neural network that it could predict the most optimal outcome for the input dataset?**

I tried making a custom optimizer but it seems to operate only on true and predicted output values.

I also tried something like this **but I don't know how to add here a correlation between outcome and input values using the aforementioned function** `F(args: tuple) => tuple`:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array(x)  # Input values with shape (N, 11)
Y = np.array(y)  # Output values with shape (N, 4)

# Define the neural network model
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(11,)), 
    keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(4)  # Output layer for the experimental parameters
])

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
   loss = abs(y_true[:, 0] - y_pred[:, 0]) +abs(y_true[:,1]- y_pred[:, 1]) + abs(y_true[:,2]-y_pred[:, 2])    +abs(y_true[:,3]- y_pred[:, 3])
   return loss

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=custom_loss)

# Initialize lists to store training loss and experimental parameters
training_loss = []
experimental_parameters = []

# Callback function to record training loss and experimental parameters
class LossHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
   def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
      training_loss.append(logs.get('loss'))
      experimental_parameters.append(model.predict(X))  # Predict and store experimental parameters

# Create an instance of the LossHistory callback
history_callback = LossHistory()

# Train the model and use the history_callback to record training loss and parameters
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10000, batch_size=32, callbacks=[history_callback])

# Plot the training loss
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(training_loss)
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Training Loss')
plt.title('Training Loss Over Epochs')

# Plot the experimental parameters over epochs
experimental_parameters = np.array(experimental_parameters)
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
for i in range(4):
    plt.plot(experimental_parameters[:, i], label=f'Param {i + 1}')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Parameter Value')
plt.title('Experimental Parameters Over Epochs')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And to predict the results using trained model:

```
input_data = np.array([[35.5, 56.94, 10.0, 123.79, 4.7, 220.0, 12.12, 1.41, 1.36, 7.51, 6.95]])
# Make predictions using the model
predictions = model.predict(input_data)
print(predictions)
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly is the problem/error. What part is not working?

Comment: @mhenning, I have to intoduce some dependecies with the help of a function `F(...)` to improve optimization process of NN.

Comment: I still don't get the question. You have a 11-tuple as input, and the model has the 4-tuple `pred` as output and tries to optimize it towards the true 4-tuple `y_true`. In a way it is its own function F(input) -> output. What exactly does the model not do for you right now?

Comment: @mhenning, currently this model doesn't use function `F()` anywhere as you can see in the code above. It relies on the dataset that it reads from `.xlx` file